Settings not visible in DialogFlow Essentials
I am unable to view wthe settings in the Diagloflow essitials which used to come at top left corner with Agent name .
Kindly help to resolve this issue.
I am expecting to open settings (icon used to be visible ) to publish an environment in Environments tab of Agent in Dialogflow Essestials.
